# download attribute corrupt file name when using query string

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8

I have a file called in the following way: `/storage/1_aviary-image-1429352137570.jpeg?1646327099`. Within the blade view I have created a download link:

```
<a href="{{ $item['url'] }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"
                             download="{{ $item['url'] }}" target="_blank">
   <span class="fa fa-download"></span>
</a>
```

When I download the file, for some reason I get: `_storage_1_aviary-image-1429352137570.jpeg_1646327099`

As you can see the `?` was replaced by `_`.

I have never encountered this problem, could someone help me to understand what's going on?

Kind regards

Comment: What do you mean `?`? I can not see `?`

Comment: O i see. You mean query string. Can you show `$item['url']`? I can't see query string there

Comment: @WahyuKristianto I'm really sorry, this is the `$item['url']` value: `storage/1_aviary-image-1429352137570.jpeg?1646327099` question updated too

Comment: How you generating url? With `Storage::url` or something?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto yes, I simply add a timestamp as query parameter to force the cache to download a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the attribute *value* for `download` is optional, and when set will set what downloaded file will be named as. If you don't set it, then the filename will be what you for it in the `href` value.

That is, the following is valid, without setting `download`'s value:

```
<a href="somefile.txt" download>
```

Since a `?` is not a valid filename char, it is being gracefully replaced by the underscore.

The solution then is to not include the `?` for the `download`'s value, but keep it in your `href` value.

SOLUTION:

```
<a href="{{ $item['url'] }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"
                             download="{{ $item['filename'] }}" target="_blank">
   <span class="fa fa-download"></span>
</a>
```

Where `$item['filename']` would be the name of the file to download *without* the `?` and timestamp.